# Trying to print the second line of Pascal's Triangle

Tags: for-loop, pascals-triangle

Trying to print the **second** line of Pascal's Triangle which is just two 1's. 
Based on the user's input, I know that for the second line there will be a 1 at (2*rows-1)/2 and as well as at (2*rows-1)/2 + 2. I used a for loop to do this line, see below:

```
    //PRINT SECOND LINE 
for (j=1; j<=((2*rows)-1); j++){
    if ( j == (2*rows -1)/2 ){ 
        printf("\n1");
    }
    else if ( j == (2*rows -1)/2 + 2  ){
        printf ("1");
    }
    else if ( j == (2*rows -1) ){
        printf(" \n");
    }
    else{
        printf(" ");
    }
}
```

Say the user enter rows=4. Then my output is:

```
    ***1***
    1*1****
```

and not

```
    ***1***
    **1*1**
```

The * are meant to represent the spaces. The first line of the output is printed using a different code. My main concern is about the second line.

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: since you know there should be spaces between the start of line and the first `1`, why do you print `printf("\n1")` anywhere in the code?

Comment: You're right, that was the problem. I took out the \n and placed it before the for loop, and it worked. Thank you!